# How to sort two Lists

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I've two Lists, one is a List of strings and one is a List of integers.  How do I sort the integer List and also sort the string List also?  The two Lists are related to each others.

```
for example:
   listB.Add(0)
   listB.Add(3)
   listB.Add(2)

   ListA.Add("name1")
   listA.Add("name3")
   listA.Add("name2")

after sorted on the Integer List, the new List should look like below:
   ListB = 0, 2, 3
   LISTA = "name1", "name2", "name3"
```

Comment: What's the relationship between the two lists? Why can't you use dictionary instead?

Answer (score 2):

Why have a list and not a **Dictionary** and **OrderBy(x=>x.Key)**

```
Dictionary<int,string> dict = new Dictionary<int,string>();
dict.Add(0,"name1");
dict.Add(1,"name2");
dict.Add(2,"name3");
var result = dict.OrderBy(x=>x.Key);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert both to arrays and then call [Array.Sort(Array keys, Array items, int Index, int Length)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z19xf7.aspx). For example:

```
var a1 = listB.ToArray();
var a2 = listA.ToArray();
Array.Sort(a1, a2, 0. a1.Length);
listA = new List<string>(a2);
listB = new List<int>(a1);
```

Another option is to [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) them and sort:

```
var sorted = a1.Zip(a2, (first, second) => new { Key = first, Value = second })
               .OrderBy(s => s.Key)
               .ToList();

// now recreate the lists
listB = sorted.Select(s => s.Key).ToList();
listA = sorted.Select(s => s.Value).ToList();
```